# For loop in matplotlib only plots first iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I want to read several columns from a csv file and plot them on a single window. What I currently have is this:

```
fig1=pl.figure(num=1, figsize=(8, 4), dpi=80, facecolor='w',edgecolor='k')
a=np.random.rand(50,9)
ax = pl.gca() 
for i in range(0,6,2):        
    ax.errorbar(a[:,i], a[:,i+1], yerr= a[:,i+2])       
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlim(1e19, 1e22)
pl.show()
```

I get no error message, but the output is a plot with only the first iteration, when there should be three in this sample file. I have put different parts of the code in the loop but at best I get the first plot window and two empty windows which is not what I am looking for either. Why isn't the for loop cycling through the i values? Or assuming is it cycling through why is it only plotting the first one? Thanks!

UPDATE: thanks tcaswell, the x range was simply too restrictive. Classical case of not looking at the data close enough. Embarrassing.

Comment: Could you give us some sample data please?

Comment: @lambo477 I wanted to edit the post and attach the file but it doesn't look like there is that option… but the file is tab-separated columns of floats.

Comment: It is best if you provide synthetic data, like `a = np.random.rand(50, 7)`

Comment: @tcaswell Should I edit my post with what you suggest? It seems relevant that my data is an array from which I want to read columns as opposed to a list, but if it helps I'll gladly do it.

Comment: That was just an example (and I am suggesting you replace the second line).  The point is that the code in your question should be something that other people can copy-paste run.  The problem you are having is probably _not_ due to the exact values in you text file (and if they are, this exercise will prove that).

Comment: Right, I read too fast and didn't see your suggestion actually returns an array. Edited and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: When I run your code I see a separate plot for each separate iteration. I suspect that by setting `ax.set_xlim(1e19, 1e22)` you are choosing a section of the graph where you can only see one iteration. Remove this line of code and you should see all the iterations. Either that, or there is something going wrong with the way your are inputting/uploading your data.